# Dynamically create empty folder in GIT

Tags: php, git, subdomain

I have PHP web hosting with ORCHESTRA.IO. They get PHP hosting code through GIT.

I want to provide subdomains to each user, upon successful signup to website. I want to generate these user's sub domains through PHP code. The question is that whether I can create empty folder in GIT for mapping subdomains on this folder.

Is there any other better solution for dynamically generating subdomains for users.

Thanks

Comment: See also here. Funny thing is that I got -1 for exactly the same answer as there is the accepted one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/115983/how-do-i-add-an-empty-directory-to-a-git-repository

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git stores files, not folders.  The best way to get Git to track a folder is by creating a dummy file in it.

Answer (score 0):

The best is probably to create a folder and put `.gitignore` in the directory.

Content of .gitignore:

```
*
!.gitignore
```

Comment: I'd rather put an empty `.keep` file in there.

Comment: In case that you want to create  ie. `temp` directory, and you do not want to see generated content in future as changes when `git status`), .gitignore is much better approach.

Comment: In that case yes. But we cannot know that.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/115983/how-do-i-add-an-empty-directory-to-a-git-repository